# Save excel workbooks as separate CSV files using Office Scripts

Tags: excel, csv, export-to-csv, office-scripts

I wanted to automate a daily task that consumes a lot of time. There's this excel file that has many workbooks. Each workbook needs to be saved as an individual CSV file, so that I'm able to upload it to our platform.

I created the following script:

```
function saveWorksheetsAsCSV() {
  let workbook = ExcelScript.Workbook.getActiveWorkbook();
  let worksheets = workbook.getWorksheets();

  // Get the user's downloads folder path
  let downloadsFolderPath = OfficeExtension.configurableWebSystemService.getDownloadsFolderPath();

  // Get the current date and time
  let currentDate = new Date();
  let formattedDate = currentDate.getFullYear() + "-" + padNumber(currentDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + padNumber(currentDate.getDate());
  let formattedTime = padNumber(currentDate.getHours()) + "-" + padNumber(currentDate.getMinutes()) + "-" + padNumber(currentDate.getSeconds());

  worksheets.forEach(function (worksheet) {
    // Create a unique filename based on the worksheet name, date, and time
    let filename = "DiscountPrograms_" + worksheet.getName() + "_" + formattedDate + "_" + formattedTime + ".csv";
    let filePath = downloadsFolderPath + "\\" + filename;

    // Save the worksheet as CSV with semicolon delimiter
    worksheet.saveAs(filePath, ExcelScript.SaveAsFileType.CommaSeparatedValue, { delimiter: ";" });
  });
}

function padNumber(number) {
  return number.toString().padStart(2, '0');
}
```

However, when I run it, I just get these errors:

```
[13, 32] Parameter 'worksheet' implicitly has an 'any' type, but a better type may be inferred from usage.
[23, 20] Parameter 'number' implicitly has an 'any' type, but a better type may be inferred from usage.
[2, 30] Property 'Workbook' does not exist on type 'typeof ExcelScript'.
[6, 29] Cannot find name 'OfficeExtension'.
[19, 44] Property 'SaveAsFileType' does not exist on type 'typeof ExcelScript'.
[1, 10] No function of name 'main' found. Ensure the function exists and is not nested in anything.
[2, 7] Office Scripts cannot infer the data type of this variable. Please declare a type for the variable.
[3, 7] Office Scripts cannot infer the data type of this variable. Please declare a type for the variable.
[6, 7] Office Scripts cannot infer the data type of this variable. Please declare a type for the variable.
[23, 20] Office Scripts cannot infer the data type of this variable. Please declare a type for the variable.
```

Could you please help me fix it? It's my first time creating a script. Thanks!

Comment: You seem to be confusing other frameworks with Office Scripts ... it's not `office-js`.

Comment: You should use power automate for this... way easier!

Comment: While trying to solve the same issue as you, I found your question. It appears that no matter what you try, Office Scripts does not allow you to write to a file. A similar experience I have found to maybe be the case for Power Query approaches. However, what I found to be working quite nicely is a simple PowerShell script (less than a dozen lines of code in my case), which takes that Excel file, selects the columns I need, and writes a UTF-8 CSV file with my desired delimiter. If you're interested, I can post my solution here.

Answer (score -1):

Possibly too late, but look at this post in Power Automate Community:
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Cookbook/Save-XLSX-Excel-all-worksheets-as-csv/td-p/923157

The contributor proposes:

1. Creating an Office Script
2. Call that from a Power Automate Flow

Creating an Office Script.
This is done in Excel for web.
Create a new script in a new file.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
// declare variables
let wbook = workbook;
// the workbook filename
let sheetnames = new Array({});
// worksheets in the work book
let sheets = wbook.getWorksheets();
// array of items
let items = new Array({});

// get each worksheet data set
for (let i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
// try catch - errors when a sheet is blank and other possible errors
try {
items[i] = sheets[i].getUsedRange(true).getTexts();
sheetnames[i] = sheets[i].getName();
}
catch (any) { }
}

// return the worksheets array
return [items,sheetnames];
}
```

You then save this file.

Call form Power Automate Flow.
The flow will have the following steps;

[Picture of the Flow form the post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwWlV.png)

BTW - I'm still scouring web for an Office Scripts answer to just save as CSV (I only need to save a single worksheet - but can't find it)